# I keep getting error one the following argument required: -m --MODEL, how can i fix it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a folder called "computerVision" inside that folder I have `train_model.py`, `lenet.py`, and another folder called `datasets` where i store images for dataset. When I execute the `train_model.py` file i get an error:

```
- python train_model.py --dataset ../dataset/train_folder \ -m/--model output/lenet.hdf5
- Using TensorFlow backend.
- usage: train_model.py [-h] -d DATASET -m MODEL
- train_model.py: error: the following arguments are required: -m/--model
```

train_model.py

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.utils import np_utils
from lenet import LeNet
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
import os

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True, help="path to input dataset of faces")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True, help="path to output model")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the list of data and labels
data = []
labels = []

# loop over the input images
for imagePath in sorted(list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))):
    # load teh image, pre-process it, and store it in the data list
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=28)
    image = img_to_array(image)
    data.append(image)

    # extract the class label from the image path and update the label list
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-3]
    label = "smiling" if label == "1" else "not_smiling"
    labels.append(label)

# scale the raw pixel intensities to the range [0, 1]
data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0
labels = np.array(labels)

# convert the labels from integer to vector
le = LabelEncoder().fit(labels)
labels = np_utils.to_categorical(le.transform(labels), 2)

# account for skew in the labeled data
classTotals = labels.sum(axis=0)
classWeight = classTotals.max() / classTotals

# partition the data into training and testing
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# initialize the model
print("[INFO compiling model....")
model = LeNet.build(width=28, height=28, depth=1, classes=2)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the network
print("[INFO] training network....")
H = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), class_weight=classWeight, batch_size=64, epochs=15, verbose=1)

# evaluate the network
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predictions = model.predict(testX, batch_size=64)
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predictions.argmax(axis=1), target_names=le.classes_))

# save the model to disk
print("[INFO] serializing network...")
model.save(args["model"])
```

lenet.py

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K


class LeNet:
    @staticmethod
    def build(width, height, depth, classes):
        # initialize the model
        model = Sequential()
        inputShape = (height, width, depth)

        # if we are using " channels first ", update the input shape
        if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
            inputShape = (depth, height, width)

        # first set of CONV => RELU => POOL layer
        model.add(Conv2D(20, (5, 5), padding="same", input_shape=inputShape))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        # second set of CONV => RELU => Pool layer
        model.add(Conv2D(50, (5, 5), padding="same"))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

        # first and only set FC => RELU layer
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(500))
        model.add(Activation("relu"))

        # softmax classifier
        model.add(Dense(classes))
        model.add(Activation("softmax"))

        return model
```

Comment: is this your command to run it `- python train_model.py --dataset ../dataset/train_folder \ -m/--model output/lenet.hdf5` - if so why are you using both `-m` and `--model` should you not just use one or the other as they are the same thing?

Comment: Hi sir i have done these both command: 1. python train_model.py --dataset ../dataset/train_folder \ --model output/lenet.hdf5 and another one 2. python train_model.py --dataset ../dataset/train_folder \ -m/ --model output/lenet.hdf5 and these both command gave me the same error.

Comment: whats the backslash in the middle for? What about `python train_model.py -d ../dataset/train_folder/ -m output/lenet.hdf5`

Comment: Please **update** your post to include the exact ways you have tried to run the script - comments are not the correct place to do that.